# Pork chops: low and slow or high and fast?

Tags: baking, pork

How hot/long should I bake my porkchops (bone-in)? I've done a bit of google searching and have gotten mixed results. Is it better to do the low temp slow baking or high temperature but quick? Why?

Comment: It's possible to do either, depending on what you're aiming for.  Have you been running into problems with your own chops?

Comment: Moisture is relevant here too. If you're baking in a gravy you want to take it slower.

Answer (score 1):

Depends a lot on how thick they are. Thinner chops would work well with just a high-temp sear under the broiler. Whereas a thicker (for example, a double-cut chop) would be better with a two-temperature process.

I.e. Bake them until they reach the right temperature at 350 or 400, then finish under the broiler for color and flavor.

Same thing applies if you want to pan-sear first, then bake until they get to your desired internal temp.

A really-long and slow cook (AKA 225 for 4 hours) won't work well with a loin-cut, as it doesn't have enough connective tissue to breakdown.

Answer (score 0):

I don't cook the bone-in chops anymore - only the boneless medallions. Typically, I just season with salt and pepper, then quickly sear on the stovetop and stick them in the oven at 350 for 15 to 18 minutes. These numbers are for 1/2" medallions. For 1" medallions, I forego the oven and just cook in pan.

Comment: Since the OP specifies bone-in chops, this isn't exactly helpful.  "Don't use the oven" and "use boneless instead" don't address how best to cook bone-in chops in an oven.

Comment: Notice how I never say "Don't use the oven" - but rather I say "**I** forego the oven". Additionally - on the bone-in issue, I can only speak from experience (cooking boneless), and leave it up to OP to adjust relatively for bone-in.